# Standard cancel button in lightning:recordform not closing the component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

[https://imgur.com/iRrojS1->](https://imgur.com/iRrojS1-%3E) [Screenshot link 1]

[https://imgur.com/a/RqFM2rI->](https://imgur.com/a/RqFM2rI-%3E) [Screenshot link 2]

I was trying to create a new contact, by filling in the details I closed the component by clicking the cancel button and it gets closed.

But when I try to create a contact again, the field details of the previous attempt appear on the contact page.
I am using lightning:recordform to create a contact.

```
Component: 
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
            controller="ContactCmpController" 
            access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="renderSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false" />     
<aura:attribute name="wrapperResponse" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="blnSuccess" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="entityApiName" type="String" default="Contact" access="global"/>
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="List" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default=""/>

<div class="c-container"> 
    <div>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.renderSpinner }">  
            <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large"/>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
<lightning:card title="New Contact">
    <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
        <div class="slds-modal__header slds-text-color_error">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.blnSuccess}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrapperResponse.lstMessage}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2>{!item}</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
        <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm"
                                  objectApiName="{!v.entityApiName}"
                                  fields = "{!v.fields}"
                                  layoutType ="Full" 
                                  columns = "2"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.handleSave}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                  mode="edit"
                                  onerror="{!c.handleError}"
                                  oncancel="{!c.handleCancel}" >
            </lightning:recordForm>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

JS file :

```
    ({
    //on record save success
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
        var payload = event.getParams();
        // validate recordId and navigate to Detail page
        if (!$A.util.isEmpty(payload) && !$A.util.isEmpty(payload.id)) {
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                 navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": payload.id,
                "slideDevName" : 'detail'
            });
            navEvt.fire();
            
        }
        else{
            component.set("v.renderSpinner",false);
        }
     },
    
    // handle submit logic
    handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
        debugger;
        component.set("v.renderSpinner",true);
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        var recUi = component.get("v.recordId");        
        var payload = event.getParams().response;        
        var recId = '';
        var newRec = true;
        console.log('fields :: ' + fields);
        console.log('fields :: ' + JSON.stringify(fields));
        // validate New/Existing Record 
        /*if (!$A.util.isEmpty(payload)) {
            if (!$A.util.isEmpty(payload.id)) {
                recId = payload.id;
                newRec = false;
            }
        }*/
        if (!$A.util.isEmpty(recUi)) {
                recId = recUi;
                newRec = false;
        }
        var action = component.get("c.getvalidate");
        action.setParams({
            "blnNewRecord" : newRec,
            "recordId" : recId,
            "fields" : fields,
            "sObjName" : component.get("v.entityApiName")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
                if (!$A.util.isEmpty(returnValue)) {
                    component.set("v.wrapperResponse",returnValue);
                    component.set("v.blnSuccess",!returnValue.isSuccess);
                    if (returnValue.isSuccess){
                        fields["RecordTypeId"] = returnValue.rtId;
                        component.find('recordForm').submit(fields);
                                            }
                    else{
                        component.set("v.renderSpinner",false);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            else{
                component.set("v.renderSpinner",false);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    handleError: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.renderSpinner",false);
    }
    ,
    //handle Cancel event
    handleCancel: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('recordForm').forEach(function(f){
            f.reset();
                                                   
        });
        // Navigate back to the record view
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        if (!$A.util.isEmpty(recId)) {
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
           navEvt.setParams({
               "recordId": recId,
               "slideDevName" : 'detail'
           });
           navEvt.fire();
           
        }
        else {
            var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
            homeEvt.setParams({
                "scope": component.get("v.entityApiName")
            });
            homeEvt.fire();
           
            
        }
    },
})
```

Please help me exploring what is being missed here.

Comment: When you pass a recordId, edit mode loads the form with input fields & displaying the specified record’s field values. on click of submit it will updated the record with specified record Id. If you want a blank form then pass recordId as null.

Comment: Thanks Amol for the suggestion, I had used refresh view in the handle cancel event and the issue has been resolved.

$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();